# Таблица с колонками

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<table class="rspn">
<tr>    
    <th colspan="3"><a class="days">Понедельник</a></th>
    <th colspan="3"><a class="days">Вторник</a></th>
    <th colspan="3"><a class="days">Среда</a></th>
    <th colspan="3"><a class="days">Четверг</a></th>
    <th colspan="3"><a class="days">Пятница</a></th>
    <th colspan="3"><a class="days">Суббота</a></th>
    <th colspan="3"><a class="days">Воскресенье</a></th>
</tr>
<tr v-for="n in 21">
    <td v-for="k in 7">
        <td class="time">{{n}}:00</td>
        <td>
            <select class="program">
                <option v-for="s in 4" value="value">Значение {{s}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="timecat">
                <option v-for="d in 4" value="value">{{d}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так ? Как мне добиться такого результата как на фото ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `<td v-for="k in 7">...</td>` на `<template v-for="k in 7">...</template>`
Должно получиться более похоже на фотографию сразу же.

Comment: Подскажите, почему с помощью template заработало?

Comment: потому что на выходе получилась как положено 21 колонка, а не 7 с непонятными внутренностями.